# C# cannot get values from list of objects

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have my main Program class that calls the `StronyElementuStrukt` procedure

```
List<object> monthlyPages = new List<object>();
monthlyPages =  StronyElementuStrukt(loginGuid, "8B35134E10A8432DB1A8C06A58427988");
```

Here is the procedure - a method that builds a list of xml nodes and returns it to the main Program class:

```
public static List<object> StronyElementuStrukt(string LoginGUID, string LinkGUID)
{
    List<object> listPages = new List<object>();

    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument(); // tworzenie nowego obiektu - dokument xml z odpowiedzia serwera
    document.LoadXml(response.Result); //wczytywanie xmla z odpowiedzia serwera do obiektu
    XmlNode pageNode = document.SelectSingleNode("/IODATA/PAGES/PAGE"); //deklaracja noda xmlowego

    if (pageNode != null) //jeżeli PAGE node istnieje
    {
        XmlNodeList nodeList = document.SelectNodes("//PAGE");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            listPages.Add(node);
        }
        return listPages;
    }
}
```

In the main Program Class I need to pick up value of xml `id` attribute, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
foreach (object monthlyPage in monthlyPages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(monthlyPage.Attributes["id"].Value);
}
```

The problem is that when I try to get the `id` I get the following error:

> Error 6   'object' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes' and no
>   extension method 'Attributes' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Could you tell me how to reach to xml attributes in the foreach loop, please? Please ask if something is not clear enough.

Comment: Why not use `List<XmlNode>`?  Also there is no need to assign a new empty list to `monthlyPages` before reassigning the results of `StronyElmentStrukt`.

Comment: Brilliant, it works, I changed it from `List<object>` to `List<XmlNode>`. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the method to return a `List<XmlNode>`.

```
public static List<XmlNode> StronyElementuStrukt(string LoginGUID, string LinkGUID)
{
    List<XmlNode> listPages = new List<object>();

    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument(); // tworzenie nowego obiektu - dokument xml z odpowiedzia serwera
    document.LoadXml(response.Result); //wczytywanie xmla z odpowiedzia serwera do obiektu
    XmlNode pageNode = document.SelectSingleNode("/IODATA/PAGES/PAGE"); //deklaracja noda xmlowego

    if (pageNode != null) //jeżeli PAGE node istnieje
    {
        XmlNodeList nodeList = document.SelectNodes("//PAGE");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            listPages.Add(node);
        }
    }

    return listPages;
}
```

Then this will work.

```
List<XmlNode> monthlyPages = StronyElementuStrukt(
    loginGuid, 
    "8B35134E10A8432DB1A8C06A58427988");

foreach (XmlNode monthlyPage in monthlyPages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(monthlyPage.Attributes["id"].Value);
}
```

Note that you could just change the `foreach` to declare `monthlyPage` as `XmlNode` instead of `object` and it will do a cast for you.  But it is better to be specific with the types you are putting into a generic collection.

Answer (score 0):

I changed all occurences from `List<object>` to `List<XmlNode>`. So the code now looks like this: 
Main Program:

```
List<XmlNode> monthlyPages = new List<XmlNode>();
monthlyPages =  StronyElementuStrukt(loginGuid, "8B35134E10A8432DB1A8C06A58427988");
foreach (XmlNodemonthlyPage in monthlyPages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(monthlyPage.Attributes["id"].Value);
}
```

Procedure:

```
    public static List<XmlNode> StronyElementuStrukt(string LoginGUID, string LinkGUID)
{
        List<XmlNode> listPages = new List<XmlNode>();

        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument(); // tworzenie nowego obiektu - dokument xml z odpowiedzia serwera
        document.LoadXml(response.Result); //wczytywanie xmla z odpowiedzia serwera do obiektu
        XmlNode pageNode = document.SelectSingleNode("/IODATA/PAGES/PAGE"); //deklaracja noda xmlowego

        if (pageNode != null) //jeżeli PAGE node istnieje
        {
            XmlNodeList nodeList = document.SelectNodes("//PAGE");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                listPages.Add(node);
            }
            return listPages;
        }
    }
```